# Como deixar o mapa do Google assim?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Existe alguma maneira de estilizar o mapa do google desse jeito?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

O maps permite uma customização bem ampla. Eu não sei necessariamente como você deseja exibir para lhe informar exatamente quais propriedades alterar. Vou deixar aqui um [tutorial bem explicado](http://tableless.com.br/api-google-maps-v3/) em português, postado na Tableless e a [documentação de estilização](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/) da própria google em inglês, espero que ajude. Não tem muito mistério

http://tableless.com.br/api-google-maps-v3/

https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/

Comment: Olha, [aqui tem mais](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling?hl=pt-br#map_features) sobre isso.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possível. Existe uma ferramenta bem util para isso [aqui (link)](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) onde podes mudar o que quiseres e depois exportas um JSON que podes passar ao objeto `options` do construtor do GooGle Maps. Um exemplo:

```
styles: [{
    "stylers": [{
      "hue": "#ccff00"
    }, {
      "saturation": -100
    }]
}],
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gnqogh6s/

A documentação oficial para configurar os estilos encontra-se [aqui (link)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#map_features).